Can I use signed JWT instead of client ID, secret with AWS cognito
Is it possible to use a signed JWT to get an access token from AWS cognito? I can use client ID, client secret with grant_type as client_credentials. But in my experience if I want to exchange a JWT, the grant_type needs to be jwt-bearer. I am not seeing any options in cognito to update grant type or make any adjustments to exchange signed JWT instead of client id, secret

You cannot because they have distinct purposes and work together in the authentication and authorization process. The Client ID identifies the application and initiate the process. The JWT identifies the authenticated user and is used to prove the user's identity and authorize access to resources.
